# Does Jade watch *.jade files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have no idea how Jade works internally, but I am guessing that it is compiling every template file once and then uses a compiled and cached version for every HTTP request.

When I have my Express app running and I make changes to my *.jade files, the changes are visible immeditaly in the browser without restarting the app.

**How does that work?**

- Is Jade watching the *.jade files in the `/views` folder?
- Is Jade checking the modified date on every HTTP request and recompile the template accordingly?
- Is Jade actually compiling the HTML on EVERY HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Express documentation at http://expressjs.com/api.html (under 'settings')

> `view cache` Enables view template compilation caching, enabled in production by default.

So

```
app.set('view cache', true);
```

...would force cahcing. But as the docs clearly state, caching defaults to on when you run your app with `NODE_ENV=production` as you should. If no environment is specified, Node defaults to 'development' and in that case template caching is disabled.

Comment: Does this mean that every template is actually compiled at EVERY HTTP request as long as I am in development mode?

Comment: Mmh, my changes to *.jade files are also visible immeditaly without restarting the app even when I am in production mode.